# unable to view existing data of my windows D partition which is now ubuntu host partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I am new to linux environment.I've installed dual boot ubuntu with windows directly downloading from the internet. Now I am able to see my windows C Partition but unable to view the existing data of my windows D partition which is actually now ubuntu host partition i've checked it by download gparted partition editor.

Comment: Uh.. how did you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: i think u have installed Ubuntu on D partition ...

Answer (score 1):

your windows D partition mounted on /host

to access it open nautilus, on the sidebar click **Filesystem** and now you can see the  **host** folder that's your windows D partition

Comment: Thank you.. is it possible to have this drive mounted under devices

Comment: no, but you can create a bookmark
go to /host folder then click Bookmark -> Add Bookmark and you can rename it with what you want eg: "Windows D"